# Expand/Collapse UITableViewCell height on click of switch button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I wanted to Expand/Collapse my `UITableViewCell` height on click of switch button action that is situated at `UITableViewCell` In swift 3.0.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855832/expanding-and-collapsing-table-view-cells-in-ios?rq=1

Comment: NO this is not working I don't want to click on cell,I want to expand on click of switch button.

Comment: You have to set the action for the button in `viewcontroller` which implements `uitableview` on `button action` you have to `reload` `tableview` with new height for the `selected cell`

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide different heights for `UITableView` row in this function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat{

    if(selectedIndexPath == indexPath){
        return 200
    }
    return 60
}
```

*Note: `selectedIndexPath` is the index path of cell to be expanded.*

You will have to reload the selected cell on Expand Button like this:

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

Or for better animations you can use below function instead of `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.endUpdates()},completion:({ _ in
  }))
```