# Dynamic expandable and collapsed table view cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, expandablelistview

I developed expandable and collapsed table view for dynamic data comes from the server. I'm displaying state names in header view successfully, but I can't displaying child data that is districts related to state names.

I followed Link for this http://www.iostute.com/2015/04/expandable-and-collapsable-tableview.html

My data is

```
_response =  @{@"Response":@{@"status":@"SUCCESS",@"error_code":@"0",@"message":@"SUCCESS",@"Array":@[
@{@"state_id":@"0",@"state_name":@"null",@"district_id":@"0",@"district_name":@"null"},
@{@"state_id":@"01",@"state_name":@"State1",@"district_id":@"001",@"district_name":@"State1District1"},
@{@"state_id":@"02",@"state_name":@"State2",@"district_id":@"004",@"district_name":@"State2District1"},
@{@"state_id":@"02",@"state_name":@"State2",@"district_id":@"005",@"district_name":@"State3District1"},
@{@"state_id":@"01",@"state_name":@"State1",@"district_id":@"002",@"district_name":@"State1District2"},
@{@"state_id":@"01",@"state_name":@"State1",@"district_id":@"003",@"district_name":@"State1District3"},
@{@"state_id":@"03",@"state_name":@"State3",@"district_id":@"006",@"district_name":@"State3District1"},
@{@"state_id":@"04",@"state_name":@"State4",@"district_id":@"008",@"district_name":@"State4District1"},
@{@"state_id":@"04",@"state_name":@"State4",@"district_id":@"009",@"district_name":@"State4District2"},
@{@"state_id":@"04",@"state_name":@"State4",@"district_id":@"010",@"district_name":@"State4District3"},
@{@"state_id":@"05",@"state_name":@"State5",@"district_id":@"011",@"district_name":@"State5District1"},
@{@"state_id":@"05",@"state_name":@"State5",@"district_id":@"012",@"district_name":@"State5District2"},
@{@"state_id":@"03",@"state_name":@"State3",@"district_id":@"007",@"district_name":@"State3District2"}]}, @"count":@"6"};
```

My code is

```
if ([[[_response objectForKey:@"Response"] objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"SUCCESS"] && (!(_integer == 0))) {

_stateID = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_stateName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_districtID = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_districtName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_stateIdStateNameDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

//Add arrays to array to remove null values dynamically
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:_stateID, _stateName, _districtID, _districtName, nil];

for (int i=0; i<_integer; i++) {
    [_stateID addObject:[[[[_response objectForKey:@"Response"] objectForKey:@"Array"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"state_id"]];
    [_stateName addObject:[[[[_response objectForKey:@"Response"] objectForKey:@"Array"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"state_name"]];
    [_districtID addObject:[[[[_response objectForKey:@"Response"] objectForKey:@"Array"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"district_id"]];
    [_districtName addObject:[[[[_response objectForKey:@"Response"] objectForKey:@"Array"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"district_name"]];

     //Remove null values
     for (int j=0; j<arr.count; j++) {
         for (NSMutableArray *ar in arr) {
             if ([[ar objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || [[ar objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"null"] || [[ar objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
               [ar addObject:@""];
               [ar removeObjectAtIndex:i];
              }
          }
       }

     }



//Add arrays to mutable array to remove empty objects
NSMutableArray *marr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:_stateID, _stateName, _districtID, _districtName, nil];
 //Remove empty objects from all arrays
 for (int j=0; j<marr.count; j++) {
  for (int i=0; i<[[marr objectAtIndex:j] count]; i++) {
      if ([[[marr objectAtIndex:j] objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@""]) {
         [[marr objectAtIndex:j] removeObjectAtIndex:i];
      }
   }
 }

//Remove duplicates from state names array
_stateName = [_stateName valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];
NSString *districtName = @"";
NSString * superater = @"&&";
_mdic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

for (int j=0; j<_stateName.count; j++) {
 for (int i=0; i<_integer; i++) {
     if ([[_stateName objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:[[[[_response objectForKey:@"Response"] objectForKey:@"Array"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"state_name"]]) {
       //Remove district name if empty or null
       if ([districtName isEqualToString:@""] || [districtName isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
          districtName = [[[[_response objectForKey:@"Response"] objectForKey:@"Array"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"district_name"];
          if ([districtName isEqual:[NSNull null]] || [districtName isEqualToString:@"null"]) {
             districtName = @"";
           }
        } else {
        //Add all districts with superater &&
        districtName = [districtName stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", superater, [[[[_response objectForKey:@"Response"] objectForKey:@"Array"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"district_name"]]];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                            //Create district names dictionary with state name keys
                            [_mdic setValue:districtName forKey:[_stateName objectAtIndex:j]];
                            districtName = @"";
                        }
                        NSLog(@"_mdic %@", _mdic);

                        _arrayForBool=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                        //Save bool value " NO " based on sectionTitleArray count.
                        for (int i=0; i<[_stateName count]; i++) {
                            [_arrayForBool addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
                        }

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            [_availableOrdersTableView reloadData];
                        });

                    } else {
}
```

// TableView delegates

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   return [_mdic count];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
//  Number of rows in each section
if ([[_arrayForBool objectAtIndex:section] boolValue]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [_stateName objectAtIndex:section]);
    NSLog(@"%@", _mdic);
    NSArray *mdicKeys = [_mdic allKeys];
    for (int i=0; i<_mdic.count; i++) {
        if ([[mdicKeys objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[_stateName objectAtIndex:section]]) {
            NSString *str = [_mdic objectForKey:[_stateName objectAtIndex:section]];
            NSLog(@"%@", str);
            _subDistrictArr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"&&"];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"_subDistrictIDArr %@", _subDistrictArr);
 return _subDistrictArr.count;
} else {
    return 0;
}
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//Create cell
static NSString *cellid=@"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellid];
if (cell==nil) {
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellid];
}

BOOL manyCells  = [[_arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue];

/********** If the section supposed to be closed *******************/
if(!manyCells)
{
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.text=@"";
}
/********** If the section supposed to be Opened *******************/
else {
    cell.textLabel.text=[_subDistrictArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0f];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f];
    }
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone ;
}
cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

/********** Add a custom Separator with cell *******************/
UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 48, _availableOrdersTableView.frame.size.width-15, 1)];
separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];

return cell;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UIView *sectionView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _availableOrdersTableView.frame.size.width, 50)];
    sectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    sectionView.tag=section;
    UILabel *viewLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _availableOrdersTableView.frame.size.width, sectionView.frame.size.height)];
    viewLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    viewLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        viewLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];
    } else {
        viewLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    }
    viewLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_stateName objectAtIndex:section]];
    _stateIDString = [_stateID objectAtIndex:section];
    NSLog(@"stateIDString %@", _stateIDString);
    [sectionView addSubview:viewLabel];

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(sectionView.frame.size.width-45, (sectionView.frame.size.height-25)/2, 18, 17)];
        imgView.tag = section;
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DA"];
        [sectionView addSubview:imgView];
    } else {
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(sectionView.frame.size.width-35, (sectionView.frame.size.height-25)/2, 18, 17)];
        imgView.tag = section;
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DA"];
        [sectionView addSubview:imgView];
    }

    /********** Add a custom Separator with Section view *******************/
    UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, sectionView.frame.size.height, _availableOrdersTableView.frame.size.width, 1)];
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [sectionView addSubview:separatorLineView];

    /********** Add UITapGestureRecognizer to SectionView   **************/
    UITapGestureRecognizer  *headerTapped   = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionHeaderTapped:)];
    [sectionView addGestureRecognizer:headerTapped];

    return sectionView;

}

- (void)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:gestureRecognizer.view.tag];
//    _gestureInteger = gestureRecognizer.view.tag;
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    BOOL collapsed  = [[_arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue];

    for (int i=0; i<[_stateName count]; i++) {
        if (indexPath.section==i) {
                [_arrayForBool replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!collapsed]];
        }
    }

    [_availableOrdersTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:gestureRecognizer.view.tag] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
   // [_availableOrdersTableView reloadData];
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two solution for this

(1) initially you put numberofrow for any section is zero and after click on any section you can add row for for clicked section.

(2) number of section will be one and you need to use two cell "cellwithheaderonly" and "cellwithheaderandsubpart" initially you will use "cellwithheaderonly" and when user will click on any cell you need to use "cellwithheaderandsubpart"

You can take reference from following URL

[Expanding and Collapsing table view cells in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855832/expanding-and-collapsing-table-view-cells-in-ios)

https://www.anexinet.com/blog/expandable-collapsible-uitableview-sections/

Comment: I followed this link https://www.anexinet.com/blog/expandable-collapsible-uitableview-sections/ , and it's working successfully. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You have to maintain an array given below : -

```
lat arr = [[“name”:”firstRow” , “subRowArray”:[1,2,3,4]],[“name”:”secondRow” , “subRowArray”:[1,2,3,4]],[“name”:”thirdRow” , “subRowArray”:[1,2,3,4]]]
```

then expand and collapse according to your array .
if would you like to use library then go for [expendable Tableview](https://github.com/sakkaras/SKSTableView)